# Joomla VirtueMart creating wholesale items

Tags: web, joomla, store, virtuemart

I have a shop setup, but want my wholesales to be able to use the shop as well.  Is there a way to create items that only the wholesalers can see?

I know you can change the pricing based on the group, but I want wholesalers to see a different set of item.

Can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

a) Could you not place them into different categories for different users

b) use the Special login level to require higher access for these categories?

Or do you want to automate what is visible to whom? In this case a query rewriter based on a system plugin may work. Look at how Joomfish does this.